# Text cut-off with Select2 and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm currently having an issue with a form that uses Select2 to make a selection look nicer (and more functional) in combination with a bootstrap layout.

The issue is that the longest element(s) of a selection are cut off after they're selected. While it's not an issue for the selection itself, it looks strange (especially with short values) and makes it unnecessary hard for users to check what they selected. See the following screenshot for an example. In that case a user would not be able to check whenever he selected A or B without reopening the selection list.

[image: selection error]

From what I can tell the issue might be caused by the `width` set on the top level `span` that is used by Select2 to do its thing. I'm unsure on how to fix it and what would be the best approach to do so. It feels like it would be the best to make that top level span ever so slightly bigger but I'm not sure how to figure out where it's set.

Another approach would be to set the `text-overflow` attribute to not be `ellipsis`. But I feel like I'm missing something more obvious. I can't image that this hasn't been an issue before.

Are my approaches sound or am I missing an [option for Select2](https://select2.github.io/options.html) that could fix this?

The code for a MWE is as follows, using JQuery 1.12 and Select2 4.0.3. It's also available as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9hratqj/2/).

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("JS");
      $("select").select2({});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selection">
      <option>Something</option>
      <option>Something different A</option>
      <option>Something different B</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use !important to override the width set by the plugin and set a minimum width for that top level span, on firefox, it shows all text, no ellipsis, only on chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also add padding in the select div like this

```css
#selection{padding:10px;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("JS");
      $("select").select2({});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selection">
      <option>Something</option>
      <option>Something different A</option>
      <option>Something different B</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this is working I don't really get why. I guess Select2 does some kind of measurement on the base selection list. Within the DOM the element I suspect to have the "wrong" dimension adjusts according to the padding on the select while it's a neighbor element.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

If you set the `min-width` so you will rid out with small text.

```
#selection {
  min-width:150px;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "rid out" but this approach is working and from the current answers the one which is he easiest to understand. While it actually has the same "issue" as the one from v-stackOverFollower.

Answer (score 1):

You can **wrap** the **select** with a `wrapper div` and give that **wrapper** a **max-width** and giving the **select** `width:100%`.

> HTML-

```
<div class="select--wrapper">
  <select id="selection">
      <option>Something</option>
      <option>Something different A</option>
      <option>Something different B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

> Css-

```
.select--wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%
}

#selection {
  width: 100%;
}
```

> Here is an working example-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select").select2({});
});
```

```css
.select--wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%
}

#selection {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>


<div class="select--wrapper">
  <select id="selection">
      <option>Something</option>
      <option>Something different A</option>
      <option>Something different B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to this in comparison to the approach of setting a `min-width` for the select?

Comment: It will help you in making responsive designs (mobile,tablet, desktop compatible). As you dont have to define the width again and again for your select .

Comment: Oh that's a good point but with your design I'd have to change it anyway, right? Currently you're setting `select--wrapper` to a fixed size of 200px. As it will always be 100% wide up to a maximum of those 200px it will always be 200px wide. At least that does seems to be the case in my limited testing. As I don't really have to focus on responsiveness I'm probably going to use the `min-width` approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after much research, this is a known issue since 2012, and looks like it will be fixed in Select2 4.1.0-beta.0

[Github issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/291)

For now, you can temporarily fix it by using the following CSS:

```
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
       width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do it directly in the definition of your select2, like this:

```
selection = $('#selection');        
selection.select2({
  width: 'auto !important'
});
```

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work best because the select2 uses flexbox:

```css
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-search.select2-search--inline {
     flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS code fixed my issue.

```
.select2-container .select2-selection__rendered > *:first-child.select2-search--inline {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.select2-container .select2-selection__rendered > *:first-child.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Reference :- [GitHub](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/4898#issuecomment-408568031)